# Getting the name of file download using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

So I'm downloading a file using Selenium and it works fine but I need to get the name of the file.

My variable `path` should get the name of what was downloaded but all it prints out is "none".

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=Binary)
driver.get("stuff")
time.sleep(2)
path = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'tgz')]").click()
print path
```

Comment: Did you try just `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'DEVcrt.sp1')]")` ? I suspect the `click()` method returns `None`

Comment: Without the click it wont download the file, the click is like a mouse clikc as far as i understand

Comment: Yes, I know that. But does it return the actual path? If so, then you can print out said path and then you can probably call path.click()

Comment: yea @MikeDriscoll `click()` returns None

Answer (score 7):

This is an alternate solution to [@TehTris](https://stackoverflow.com/u/2193134)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26371425/2932244).

It is not necessary that all the links will contain the file name (they can also be redirects at times), so in that case you can try checking the difference in the directory listing before and after downloading the file by using [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir).

```
import os

before = os.listdir('/home/jason/Downloads')

# Download the file using Selenium here

after = os.listdir('/home/jason/Downloads')
change = set(after) - set(before)
if len(change) == 1:
    file_name = change.pop()
else:
    print "More than one file or no file downloaded"
```

Answer (score 0):

first you would get the link object, so you can do stuff to it:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'DEVcrt.sp1')]")
```

then you would get the "href" attribute from the link object:

```
path = link.get_attribute("href") #this will return something like 'www.booger.com/file.exe'
```

then you click on the link object:

```
link.click()
```