# Get filename of downloaded file using Python + Selenium

Tags: python, css, linux, selenium, upload

I have a Python program that downloads a file from a website. The file is downloaded via `By.CSS_SELECTOR` in a CSS set of options, and no URL is provided for the original file on the website (so can't call or capture the specific URL, at least not that I'm aware of). The command to download the file via Selenium looks something like this:

```
self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".templateOptionButton:nth-child(1) > .export_option_button:nth-child(1)").click()
```

This will download the file to my Browser's download directory.

**Is there a way to capture the filename of the downloaded file?** I have another function where I want to re-upload the same file I downloaded (the file is deleted from the system after it's downloaded). The filepath will need to be `C:\\fakepath\\system.1.xml` (I'm using Linux), where `system.1.json` is the filename of the downloaded file: `system` would be the name of the online too and `1` the numbered entry (it's a database).

It only downloads and uploads `.xml` files, if that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this class:

```
import glob
import time
import os

class FileWaiter:

def __init__(self, path: str):
    self.path = path
    self.files = set(glob.glob(path))

def wait_new_file(self, timeout: int) -> set:
    """
    Waits for a new file to be created and returns the new file path.
    """
    endtime = time.time() + timeout
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        diff_files = set(glob.glob(self.path)) - self.files
        if diff_files:
            self.files = set(glob.glob(self.path))
            return diff_files
        if time.time() > endtime:
            raise Exception("No downloaded files")
```

you have to initialize your FileWaiter object with the path to your download folder so the steps are the following:

```
waiter = FileWaiter(os.path.join('path_to_download_folder', '*.xml'))
self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".templateOptionButton:nth-child(1) > .export_option_button:nth-child(1)").click()
files_list = waiter.wait_new_file(timeout=10)
```

1. initialize your FileWaiter object with the extension of the file you want to download
2. click the button
3. call the `wait_new_file` function of your object that returns the set of the downloaded file names

Comment: so interesting, but it should be more simply

`change = set(after) - set(before)
if len(change) == 1:
    file_name = change.pop()`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370150/getting-the-name-of-file-download-using-selenium-in-python